# Clustering latitude longitude data based on distance

Tags: python, software-recommendations, clustering, spatial-cluster

I have a large dataset of latitude and longitude. I want to cluster the data into groups based on distance such that the distance between two points in a cluster is not greater than a minimum specified value. Also the number of clusters are not fixed. But there must be a minimum specified number of points to make a cluster. If the number of point are less than a specified minimum, they wont be considered as a cluster. 
I am trying to find out what library and packages in python can help me cluster this.

Comment: Duplicate: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194873/clustering-geographical-data-based-on-point-location-and-associated-point-values?rq=1
Similar: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195539/clustering-of-spatial-data-in-r-or-python?rq=1
Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144229/how-to-cluster-points-into-clusters-of-a-maximum-diameter-in-postgis/144230#144230